# having a custom UIView in a UIViewcontroller

Tags: swift, user-interaction

I created a UIView class and implemented it inside a viewcontroller. However, I have a some other things in the view controller that I want to be able to interact with but I cannot do that because of the attached view.

how do I interact with the base viewcontroller while the custom uiview is present in the viewcontroller

```
var tripView: TripView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tripView = TripView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.view.addSubview(tripView)
        // AutoLayout
        tripView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges(with: UIEdgeInsets.zero)

    }
```

Comment: Set 'tripView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false' then you can interact other things which are there behind tripView.

Comment: this does not enable me interact with the element in the UIView

Comment: @AshokPolu I have a UIImage in the UIView, I want to be able to interact with the UIImage

Comment: If that is the case you can only interact 'tripView' but not behind views. Both can not possible to interact at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
class TripView:UIView {

    // add this
class TransView:UIView {

    var imgV1:UIImageView!
    var imgV2:UIImageView!

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

        return imgV1.frame.contains(point) ||  imgV2.frame.contains(point) // or ![imgV1,imgV2].filter{$0.frame.contains(point)}.isEmpty
    }

}
```

Comment: this does not enable me interact with the element in the UIView

Comment: I have a UIImage in the UIView, I want to be able to interact with the UIImage

Comment: it works now. What if in a case I have more elements in the UIView how do I add them since the return statement take only one value

Answer (score 2):

You should assign proper index to your views by using following methods from [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview). 
Instance Methods: [aboveSubview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622570-insertsubview) and [belowSubview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622598-insertsubview) or [insertSubview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622538-insertsubview)
.

> From UIView overview

Views can be nested inside other views to create view hierarchies, which offer a convenient way to organize related content. Nesting a view creates a parent-child relationship between the child view being nested (known as the subview) and the parent (known as the superview). A parent view may contain any number of subviews but each subview has only one superview. By default, when a subview’s visible area extends outside of the bounds of its superview, no clipping of the subview's content occurs. 
Hope it helps!