# Interacting with custom UIView inside view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am created a UIView which I want to display in my view controller. I have created the UIView and it shows with other UI components, but the problems I have now is I con not interact with the elements of the on the UIView.

below is my code

```
class SliderView: CustomView {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderText: UILabel!

    override func initialize() {
        super.initialize()

        let name = String(describing: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: name, bundle: .main)
        nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)

        self.addSubview(self.containerView)
        self.containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            self.containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            self.containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            ])
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return sliderImage.frame.contains(point)
    }

@IBAction func clickme(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("SWIPPERD minmax22g")
}

}
```

in the viewcontroller

```
weak var sliderView: SliderView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let sliderView = SliderView()
        self.view.addSubview(sliderView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sliderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            sliderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            sliderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            ])
        self.sliderView = sliderView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sliderView.sliderText.text = "HOOOOO WORKS"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [having a custom UIView in a UIViewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648327/having-a-custom-uiview-in-a-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: @JordiGámez it is not a duplicate. This is a separate question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You shouldn't add an outlet as a subview again inside the custom view

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
self.addSubview(self.containerView)
```

add this method and use it to get an instance

```
static func getInstance() -> SliderView { 
   return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SliderView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! SliderView
}
```

2- This will make the imageView the only active frame inside the view

```
return sliderImage.frame.contains(point)
```

3- Don 't add the subview inside `loadView` , add it inside `viewDidLoad`

```
let sliderView = SliderView()
```

to

```
let sliderView = SliderView.getInstance()
```

Comment: The app crashes `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors`

Comment: where would the getInstance be called?